# Consistent assert for parallel runs in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, assert, mpi4py

it seems to me that in a python code that runs in parallel, an assert that is failed by at least one processor should abort all the processors, so that:

1) the error message is clearly visible (with the stack trace)

2) the remaining processors do not keep waiting forever.

However this is not what the standard assert does.

This question has already been asked in
[python script running with mpirun not stopping if assert on processor 0 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120286/python-script-running-with-mpirun-not-stopping-if-assert-on-processor-0-fails)
but I am not satisfied by the answer. There it is suggested to use the comm.Abort() function, but this only answers point 2) above.

So I was wondering: is there a standard "assert" function for parallel codes (eg with mpi4py), or should I write my own assert for that purpose?

Thanks!

Edit -- here is my try (in a class but could be outside), which can surely be improved:

```
import mpi4py.MPI as mpi
import traceback

class My_code():

    def __init__(self, some_parameter=None):

        self.current_com = mpi.COMM_WORLD
        self.rank = self.current_com.rank
        self.nb_procs = self.current_com.size

        self.my_assert(some_parameter is not None)
        self.parameter = some_parameter
        print "Ok, parameter set to " + repr(self.parameter)

    # some class functions here...

    def my_assert(self, assertion):
        """
        this is a try for an assert function that kills 
        every process in a parallel run
        """
        if not assertion:
            print 'Traceback (most recent call last):'
            for line in traceback.format_stack()[:-1]:
                print(line.strip())
            print 'AssertionError'
            if self.nb_procs == 1:
                exit()
            else:
                self.current_com.Abort()
```

Comment: You might consider https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mpi4py/me2TFzHmmsQ which appears in the search: `mpi4py stop on exception`

Comment: Thanks for the link ! I am writing an answer based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the following piece of code answers the question. It is derived from the discussion pointed by Dan D.

```
import mpi4py.MPI as mpi
import sys


# put this somewhere but before calling the asserts
sys_excepthook = sys.excepthook
def mpi_excepthook(type, value, traceback): 
    sys_excepthook(type, value, traceback) 
    if mpi.COMM_WORLD.size > 1:
        mpi.COMM_WORLD.Abort(1) 
sys.excepthook = mpi_excepthook 

# example:
if mpi.COMM_WORLD.rank == 0:
    # with sys.excepthook redefined as above this will kill every processor
    # otherwise this would only kill processor 0
    assert 1==0          

# assume here we have a lot of print messages
for i in range(50):
    print "rank = ", mpi.COMM_WORLD.rank

# with std asserts the code would be stuck here 
# and the error message from the failed assert above would hardly be visible
mpi.COMM_WORLD.Barrier()
```